# How do I count size of every word in this string?

Tags: java, string

I want to be able to output the letter size of each word. So far my code only outputs the letter size of the first word. How do I get it to output the rest of the words?

```java
import java.util.*;

public final class CountLetters {
  public static void main (String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String words = sc.next();
    String[] letters = words.split(" ");

    for (String str1 : letters) {
       System.out.println(str1.length() ); 
    }   
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just because [`next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) returns only the first word (or also called the first 'token'):

```
String words = sc.next();
```

To read the entire line, use `nextLine`:

```
String words = sc.nextLine();
```

What you are doing should work then.

The other thing you can do is go ahead and use `next` all the way (instead of a split) because Scanner already searches for tokens using whitespace by default:

```
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(sc.next().length());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sc.next() will only let the scanner take in the first word.

```
 String words = sc.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all of the scanner values:

```
public final class CountLetters {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            String word = sc.next();
            System.out.println(word.length() );
        }
   }
}
```